# URLパラメータをformに入力、ない場合はdisabled属性にする。

Tags: javascript

URLパラメータを取得し、formのtextboxに入力したいと考えています。もし、パラメータが存在しない場合にはtextboxを非活性で表示するためにはどのようにしたらよいでしょうか。

以下では、codeというパラメータがあれば入力された状態となりますが、パラメータがなければ「undifined」となります。これをdisabled状態としたいのですが…。

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var qsParm = new Array();
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
var parms = query.split('&');
for (var i=0; i<parms.length; i++) {
var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
if (pos > 0) {
var key = parms[i].substring(0,pos);
var val = parms[i].substring(pos+1);
qsParm[key] = val;
}
}

function into(){
document.getElementById("target").value = qsParm["code"];
}
// -->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="into()">
    <form action="/hoge" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="code" id="target"><br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

以下の様にすればいいかと思います。

```
function into(){
    var element = document.getElementById("target");
    if(qsParm["code"] !== undefined){//undefined かどうか調べる
        element.value = qsParm["code"];//undefinedでないので値をセット
    } else {
        element.value = "";//以前の内容をクリア、(必要無し？)
        element.disabled = true;//disabled をセット
    }
}
```